# HDMI status is not coming in android marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, hdmi

Below android 6.0 its working perfect, but in android marshmallow HDMI status is not coming

> ```
> private boolean isHdmiSwitchSet() {
> File switchFile = new File("/sys/devices/virtual/switch/hdmi/state");
>     if (!switchFile.exists()) {
>         switchFile = new File("/sys/class/switch/hdmi/state");
>     }
>     try {
>         Scanner switchFileScanner = new Scanner(switchFile);
>         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"HDMI Status"+switchFileScanner.nextInt(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>         int switchValue = switchFileScanner.nextInt();
>         switchFileScanner.close();
>         return switchValue > 0;
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: what type of error you get?

Comment: I did not get error,Toast also not coming,its not enter into try and catch method.

Comment: check your android monitor

Comment: you define storage permission in manifest or not?

Comment: No, Just I gave  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

Comment: you must define permission for storage also and check it's allowed or not by user in run time.

Comment: No luck, Toast is not coming with storage permissions also...

Comment: try me code, before accessing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution,If we will compile like android system application with android:sharedUserId="**android.uid.system**" its working perfect...

Thank U.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps,

First, Put storage permission in `AndroidManifest` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Second, Before access file check permission allowed by user or not:

```
public boolean checkPermissionForWRITE_STORAGE(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Third, do your task on `true` condition.

Comment: not coming , i have updated my question with full of acticity